# UI Automation, reusing code within another framework or hack to make it work?

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, ui-testing

I have a lot of UI Automation JavaScript code which is no longer useable since support was dropped in Xcode.

I'm looking for any means possible to try an reuse as much of the code as possible.

I just wondered if there's is any sort of migration path or hack to make it useable ?
I haven't seen anything so far.

Comment: UI Automation was part of Xcode, you could record steps and it would produce the JS it required. You could then write standard JS code and add code to functions etc. It would rely on a framework provided by Xcode to access elements etc. I guess a new framework would be required to swap out the element access, hmm, thanks I hadn't really considered this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've waited enough for iOS QA Automation Engineers to share their professional view on the matter, but since none showed up, I'll give it a go.

First off, you are not alone. **UI Automation** support has been dropped since XCode 8 and a lot of other **[people had the same problem](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6597)**.

The main takeaway from all the materials I've read online is this:

> The only version of Appium that will work with xcode 8 is 1.6.0. You can download the beta now. **Instruments/UIAutomation have been removed** and only **Appium's XCUITest** support will work moving forward.

Moving forward, the best document to get you started with your test case migration, or at least give you some helping tips is this one: **[Migrating your iOS tests from UIAutomation (iOS 9.3 and below) to XCUITest (iOS 9.3 and up)](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-xcuitest/)** [UPDATED LINK].

The article covers some pretty hot topics considering your situation:

- Element class name schema;
- Page source;
- Locator strategies (with `xpath` emphasis);
- Dependencies, API differences, etc.

You will have to start using **[appium-xcuitest-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-xcuitest-driver)** instead of [appium-ios-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-ios-driver).

**Installation & Setup:**

Apart from the relevant info that you'll find on [appium-xcuitest-driver's official GitHub repo](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver), the bread and butter is here: **[Setting up iOS Real Devices Tests with XCUITest](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md)**.

Getting started with a new framework/set of libs, or migrating from one tool-suite to another is always hard, but from past experiences, once you have a working setup and build your first test case, everything else will go smoothly afterwards.

Finally, I could pro-long the response, but the **[official documentation](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-xcuitest/)** will always do a better job.

Hope is helps in any way, shape, or form. Cheers!